# fork D3 v5 Zoomable Sunburst has broken

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to run it locally. I've been suffering all day, but I just can't get it to work. The data is displayed, but the path is not displayed.

Made fork here: https://vizhub.com/ahlev/d77c2d3bd9a34d8c98791b89f47517fa?edit=files&file=flare.json

```js
const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/v1.1.8/test/data/flare.json";

const format = d3.format(",d");
const width = 932;
const radius = width / 6;

const arc = d3.arc()
        .startAngle(d => d.x0)
        .endAngle(d => d.x1)
        .padAngle(d => Math.min((d.x1 - d.x0) / 2, 0.005))
        .padRadius(radius * 1.5)
        .innerRadius(d => d.y0 * radius)
        .outerRadius(d => Math.max(d.y0 * radius, d.y1 * radius - 1));

const partition = data => {
    const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
            .sum(d => d.size)
            .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
    return d3.partition()
            .size([2 * Math.PI, root.height + 1])
            (root);
}

d3.json(url).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    const root = partition(data);
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRainbow, data.children.length + 1));

    root.each(d => d.current = d);

    const svg = d3.select('#partitionSVG')
            .style("width", "100%")
            .style("height", "auto")
            .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

    const g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${width / 2})`);

    const path = g.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
            .join("path")
            .attr("fill", d => {
                while (d.depth > 1)
                    d = d.parent;
                return color(d.data.name);
            })
            .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
            .attr("d", d => arc(d.current));

    path.filter(d => d.children)
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .on("click", clicked);

    path.append("title")
            .text(d => `${d.ancestors().map(d => d.data.name).reverse().join("/")}\n${format(d.value)}`);

    const label = g.append("g")
            .attr("pointer-events", "none")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("user-select", "none")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
            .join("text")
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.current))
            .attr("transform", d => labelTransform(d.current))
            .text(d => d.data.name);

    const parent = g.append("circle")
            .datum(root)
            .attr("r", radius)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("pointer-events", "all")
            .on("click", clicked);

    function clicked(p) {
        parent.datum(p.parent || root);

        root.each(d => d.target = {
                x0: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x0 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
                x1: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x1 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
                y0: Math.max(0, d.y0 - p.depth),
                y1: Math.max(0, d.y1 - p.depth)
            });

        const t = g.transition().duration(750);

        // Transition the data on all arcs, even the ones that aren’t visible,
        // so that if this transition is interrupted, entering arcs will start
        // the next transition from the desired position.
        path.transition(t)
                .tween("data", d => {
                    const i = d3.interpolate(d.current, d.target);
                    return t => d.current = i(t);
                })
                .filter(function (d) {
                    return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || arcVisible(d.target);
                })
                .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.target) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
                .attrTween("d", d => () => arc(d.current));

        label.filter(function (d) {
            return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || labelVisible(d.target);
        }).transition(t)
                .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.target))
                .attrTween("transform", d => () => labelTransform(d.current));
    }

    function arcVisible(d) {
        return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && d.x1 > d.x0;
    }

    function labelVisible(d) {
        return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && (d.y1 - d.y0) * (d.x1 - d.x0) > 0.03;
    }

    function labelTransform(d) {
        const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
        const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 * radius;
        return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="partitionSVG" width="932" height="932" viewBox="0 0 932 932"></svg>
```

Just in case: https://codepen.io/nvrngrek/pen/ExKYazE

Comment: If change `d3.json(url)` on `
const {require} = new observablehq.Library;
require()('@observablehq/flare')` as in the source, then everything works, but this is the same data, why is this? please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Just change size -> value.
https://talk.observablehq.com/t/notebook-to-vanilla-javascript-steps/1644/19